# how to finish my countdown timer in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, timer, nstimer, uidatepicker

I have a countdown timer where the user can input the time they want to start from using a countdown timer like in the clock app. The problem is, I can't figure out how to make the timer actually count down. I have already made the UI and have most of the code, but I don't know what would go in the `updateTimer` method I have.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    //I don't know what goes here to make the timer decrease...
}

- (IBAction)btnStartPressed:(id)sender {
    pkrTime.hidden = YES; //this is the timer picker
    btnStart.hidden = YES;
    btnStop.hidden = NO;
    // Create the timer that fires every 60 sec    
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)btnStopPressed:(id)sender {
    pkrTime.hidden = NO;
    btnStart.hidden = NO;
    btnStop.hidden = YES;
}
```

Please let me know what goes in the `updateTimer` method to let the timer decrease.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What variable do you have to track the time? I don't see a variable for it, or is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would track the overall time left with a variable. The updateTimer method will be called every second, and you would reduce the time left variable by 1 (one second) each time updateTimer method is called. I have given an example below, but I have renamed updateTimer to reduceTimeLeft.

SomeClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    int timeLeft;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

SomeClass.m

```
#import "SomeClass.h"

@implementation SomeClass

- (IBAction)btnStartPressed:(id)sender {
    //Start countdown with 2 minutes on the clock.
    timeLeft = 120;

    pkrTime.hidden = YES;
    btnStart.hidden = YES;
    btnStop.hidden = NO;

    //Fire this timer every second.
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                selector:@selector(reduceTimeLeft:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
}

- (void)reduceTimeLeft:(NSTimer *)timer {
    //Countown timeleft by a second each time this function is called
    timeLeft--;
    //When timer ends stop timer, and hide stop buttons
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
        pkrTime.hidden = NO;
        btnStart.hidden = NO;
        btnStop.hidden = YES;

        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
    NSLog(@"Time Left In Seconds: %i",timeLeft);
}

- (IBAction)btnStopPressed:(id)sender {
    //Manually stop timer
    pkrTime.hidden = NO;
    btnStart.hidden = NO;
    btnStop.hidden = YES;

    [self.timer invalidate];
}

@end
```